# JSON parse issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{"time":"2011-11-30 04:44","countryName":"Austria","sunset":"2011-11-30 16:32","rawOffset":1,"dstOffset":2,"countryCode":"AT","gmtOffset":1,"lng":10.2,"sunrise":"2011-11-30 07:42","timezoneId":"Europe/Vienna","lat":47.01}
```

How can I parse this using javascript? I have tried using:

```
function callbackFun(data) {
        $j.each(data.result, function(i, item) {
            alert(this.time);
        });
    }
```

But it seems this is not correct.

Answer (score 5):

If you retrieve that piece of data from [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) then you could set up `dataType: 'json'` to get it automatically parsed for you.

Otherwise just use [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, it's trivial:

```
var obj = '{"time":"2011-11-30 04:44","countryName":"Austria","sunset":"2011-11-30 16:32","rawOffset":1,"dstOffset":2,"countryCode":"AT","gmtOffset":1,"lng":10.2,"sunrise":"2011-11-30 07:42","timezoneId":"Europe/Vienna","lat":47.01}';

var json = jQuery.parseJSON(obj);
alert(json.time);
alert(json.countryName);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: It's also trivial if you're not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
var MyJson = '{"time":"2011-11-30 04:44","countryName":"Austria","sunset":"2011-11-30 16:32","rawOffset":1,"dstOffset":2,"countryCode":"AT","gmtOffset":1,"lng":10.2,"sunrise":"2011-11-30 07:42","timezoneId":"Europe/Vienna","lat":47.01}';

var MyObject = jQuery.parseJSON(MyJson);
```